# How to customize static const fields by the library consumer defined in the library?

Tags: c++, coding-style

The title poorly describes what I'd like to achieve.

I have a cross-platform codebase which gets compiled on different platforms by different developers, and the core mutual codebase is maintained at a single place in source control.
In this codebase I have a class called `Config`, which defines several configuration parameters as `static const fields` like this:

```
struct Config
{
    static const bool ConfigParamA = true;

    static const int ConfigParamB = 2;

    // etc.
}
```

And I use these parameters throughout the codebase.

What I want is to give the ability for the developers who use the codebase on the different platforms (iOS, Android, Windows) to customize these config parameters for their needs.

The simplest solution would be to have them simply edit this header file at their environment, but that way they would have to edit this header every time they copy the new version of the codebase from the source control to their environment, which I'd like to avoid.

Another approach would be to simply define multiple versions of the fields in `Config` for each platform like this:

```
struct Config
{
    #ifdef WINDOWS
    static const bool ConfigParamA = true;
    // etc.
    #endif

    #ifdef ANDROID
    static const bool ConfigParamA = false;
    // etc.
    #endif

    // etc.
}
```

But this would pollute the core codebase with platform-specific `#ifdefs`, which I am trying to avoid as much as possible.

I have also thought about changing the fields to virtual functions and inherit from the Config class on every platform and override the functions. However I wouldn't like to introduce the cost of virtual calls for such a simple thing as primitive config parameters.

So is there any easier way to make the "clients" be able to customize some config parameters of the "library" without having to edit the codebase?

Comment: Are the target platforms known in advance and stable or might they change?

Comment: Pass a policy class as a template parameter

Comment: "[avoid] the cost of virtual calls" - this sounds like premature optimization to me. Unless you continuously check one of these params in a tight inner loop, the cost won't be noticeable I'd say.

Comment: lethal-guitar: they are absolutely stable.

Comment: Ben Voigt: could you elaborate on how that could be done? (how should the Config class be defined on the library side, and what should be done on the consumer side?)

Comment: lethal-guitar: I agree, and I use virtual inheritance throughout the codebase without much worry. In this particular case it's more of a "principle" than actual worry about performance. It just seems that there must be some simpler solution than virtual inheritance for this problem. I mean these are static fields (the reason they are not constexpr is because our compiler doesn't support it), so using dynamic virtual calls seems to be inherently wrong.

Comment: Are you using something like CMake or autotools, by any chance ? Those might help you solve your problems, by doing platform checks before compilation, and setting appropriate variables which could be used from the code.

Comment: SirDarius: no, the platform devs copy the codebase by hand from time to time to their development environment. Also primarily I am looking for some language-supported solution instead of some tooling automation.

Comment: So, what are you using to compile the source code ? Makefiles ? Visual Studio projects ?...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design

Comment: VS on Windows, and Eclipse and Xcode for Android/iOS (I think :))

Comment: Assuming there is a consequent codebase, I feel your pain to maintain this... CMake is definitly something you should look into (it generates Visual studio projects, or Eclipse projects, or XCode projects, or Makefiles... from a single specification, and has the ability to perform many code configuration tasks)

Comment: Ben Voigt: my problem with Policy-based design is that if I get it right, the client needs to instantiate the class with the correct policy implementation, but in this case I don't want the client to be needed to write any code if they don't want to modify the default values of the parameters. I might miss something about policy-based design that makes this possible.

Comment: The library can provide a policy, the client can either pass that class, or a subclass that replaces only a few parameters.  You can even use a default template argument to use the default policy if none is specified, but I think I'd prefer to make the client explicitly use the default policy if that's what they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution assumes you are using [CMake](http://cmake.org/).

When writing your `CMakeLists.txt` file (the equivalent of a Makefile, but at a higher level, since CMake will generate Makefiles from it), you can define user-editable variables that can be modified pretty much like the invocation of a `./configure` script.

In your case you might write something like this:

```
# default values
set(ConfigParamA FALSE)
set(ConfigParamB 0)

# default values on Windows
if(WIN32)
  set(ConfigParamA TRUE)
  set(ConfigParamB 2)
endif(WIN32)

# default values on MacOSX
if(APPLE)
  set(ConfigParamA TRUE)
  set(ConfigParamB 3)
endif(APPLE)

# user-editable cached values
set(YOURPROJECT_ConfigParamA ${ConfigParamA} CACHE BOOL "Configuration Parameter A")
set(YOURPROJECT_ConfigParamB ${ConfigParamB} CACHE STRING "Configuration Parameter B")

# convert boolean values to C++ boolean litterals
if(YOURPROJECT_ConfigParamA)
  set(ConfigParamA true)
else(YOURPROJECT_ConfigParamA)
  set(ConfigParamA false)
endif(YOURPROJECT_ConfigParamA)

configure_file(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/config.in ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/config.h)
include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

This creates default values that can be modified by a tool like `ccmake`, `cmake-gui`, or by editing the generated `CMakeCache.txt` file.

Next, you can tell CMake to generate a header file from the `config.in` template, which looks like this:

```
#define CONFIG_PARAM_A ${ConfigParamA}
#define CONFIG_PARAM_B ${ConfigParamB}
```

Invoking cmake will cause the following `config.h` file to be generated:

```
#define CONFIG_PARAM_A true
#define CONFIG_PARAM_B 2
```

Then all you have to do is include the `config.h` file before declaring your structure, and using the configured values:

```
#include "config.h"

struct Config
{
    static const bool ConfigParamA = CONFIG_PARAM_A;

    static const int ConfigParamB = CONFIG_PARAM_B;

    // etc.
};
```

A major advantage of using this approach is that the generated files are not part of the source code repository, but local to the developer machine instead. Therefore, each developer can work on his favorite platform, alter the configuration as needed without any impact on the work of other people.

Also, CMake allows each developer to work using her favorite environment/IDE, thanks to the support for a lot of widely used products.

I highly recommend learning CMake, which solves many problems when doing cross-platform C or C++ development.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I accept it, however I would be happier with a solution which only depends on code, and not on any tools. Probably I am going to end up using some simple #ifdef-s in my Config.h file, because we don't have so many platform-specific config parameters at the moment.